# Factory Reset a HM-10

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, reset, bluetooth-low-energy

I had programmed a HM-10 module to act as iBeacon with my Arduino Uno's serial monitor using the following steps:

1. AT+RENEW Restores factory defaults
2. AT+RESET Reboot HM-10
3. AT Wait for OK
4. AT+MARJ0x1234 Set iBeacon Major number to 0x1234 (hexadecimal)
5. AT+MINO0xFA01 Set iBeacon Minor number to 0xFA01 (hexadecimal)
6. AT+ADVI5 Set advertising interval to 5 (546.25 milliseconds)
7. AT+NAMEDOPEY Set HM-10 module name to DOPEY. Make this unique.
8. AT+ADTY3 Make non-connectable (save power)
9. AT+IBEA1 Enable iBeacon mode
   10.AT+DELO2 iBeacon broadcast-only (save power)
   11.AT+PWRM0 Enable auto-sleep. This reduces power from 8 to 0.18 mA
   12.AT+RESET Reboot

Now it is working as an iBeacon and one side transmitter. Now i want to reset my HM-10 module to factory settings but AT on serial monitor won't display OK as it used to. Is it now not compatible with Arduino's serial monitor? If not, how to reset my module like it was new?

Comment: You might want to link the HM-10 datasheet and any other relevant documents. We don't know what an HM-10 is.

Comment: HM-10 is Bluetooth Low Energy that implements Bluetooth version 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read in the f.. manual :-) and found this:

> HM-10 Device Terminal Functions: PIN 11 | RESETB | Reset if low >100ms.

I googled and found this:

> 1.3.1 How to wake up module from sleep mode? There are two ways to wake up module from sleep mode.
>
> 1) Send “I am iron man, I am iron man, I am iron man I am iron…..”
>   string.
>
> Yes, that is a joke, in sleep mode, you can send a long string (Length
>
> > 80 or more), that string can made module wake up, and you will receive “OK+WAKE” string through UART. That string can’t include any
> >     AT commands.
>
> 2) Long press system KEY >=1000 ms.
>
> After wake up module, you can send and receive AT commands.

Find this [here](http://eezone.co.uk/blog/wireless/hm-10-cc2541-4-0-ble-bluetooth-to-uart-transceiver-module.html). (but they quote the manual too)

(system KEY on "real" HM-10 breakouts is BRK)

Answer (score 4):

For future Googlers :

When in **AT+PWRM0**, the hm10 will go into sleep mode immediately. To wake it up, you need to send a random string of more than 80 charaters not containing an AT command. It will wake it up and it will answer with a **OK+WAKE**.

In practice, I had to send the **80+ characters string** several time in a row.

While debugging your app you should keep **AT+PWRM1** to avoid going into sleep mode while you work.

Don't forget to put it back in **AT+PWRM0** when you go into production though as it saves a lot of powers.